# How to add Jgit to your Android project?

Tags: android, android-studio, github, jgit

I have been trying to add Jgit to my android project for to execute remote push commands. i have tried ajgit and many others and none of them support "remote push".

I have tried including Jgit from source as a module. to encounter "Lambda expressions not supported in Android". gave that up and downloaded the latest jar library from official jgit site and added it as an external library and came across with the error below. which i suppose is a external dependency issue.

Please advice how i can include Jgit or any other library that would allow me to do "remote pushes" in to my android studio project so i can move on to the better part of my project. (using Maven or else.. what i need is a fast solution because my work is kind of halted due to this setback)

thank you in advance.

the code i would like to execute:

```
try{
            String httpUrl = "https://github.com/repo/branch";
            String localPath = "/sdcard/Folder1/folder2";
            Log.d("GIT","1");
            Repository localRepo = new FileRepository(localPath);
            Log.d("GIT","2");
            Git git = new Git(localRepo);
            Log.d("GIT","3");


            // add remote repo:
            RemoteAddCommand remoteAddCommand = git.remoteAdd();
            remoteAddCommand.setName("origin");
            remoteAddCommand.setUri(new URIish(httpUrl));
            // you can add more settings here if needed
            remoteAddCommand.call();

            // push to remote:
            PushCommand pushCommand = git.push();
            pushCommand.setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("username", "password"));
            // you can add more settings here if needed
            pushCommand.call();

        }catch (Exception ex){
            imessage += "/n"+ex.getMessage();
        }
```

which returns error at line ,

```
Repository localRepo = new FileRepository(localPath);


E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4
    Process: com.crimson.studio.Ruby.Ui, PID: 3847
    java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: Exception from call site #145 bootstrap method
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.SystemReader.getOsName(SystemReader.java:372)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.SystemReader.isWindows(SystemReader.java:350)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.SystemReader.setPlatformChecker(SystemReader.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.SystemReader.init(SystemReader.java:187)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.SystemReader.<clinit>(SystemReader.java:83)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.SystemReader.getInstance(SystemReader.java:160)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS$FSFactory.detect(FS.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS.detect(FS.java:306)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS.detect(FS.java:279)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS.<clinit>(FS.java:269)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BaseRepositoryBuilder.setupWorkTree(BaseRepositoryBuilder.java:657)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BaseRepositoryBuilder.setup(BaseRepositoryBuilder.java:589)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.<init>(FileRepository.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.<init>(FileRepository.java:165)
        at com.crimson.studio.Ruby.VulkanActivity.showAlert(VulkanActivity.java:58)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Bootstrap method returned null
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.SystemReader.getOsName(SystemReader.java:372) 
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.SystemReader.isWindows(SystemReader.java:350) 
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.SystemReader.setPlatformChecker(SystemReader.java:197) 
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.SystemReader.init(SystemReader.java:187) 
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.SystemReader.<clinit>(SystemReader.java:83) 
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.SystemReader.getInstance(SystemReader.java:160) 
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS$FSFactory.detect(FS.java:131) 
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS.detect(FS.java:306) 
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS.detect(FS.java:279) 
        at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FS.<clinit>(FS.java:269) 
        at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BaseRepositoryBuilder.setupWorkTree(BaseRepositoryBuilder.java:657) 
        at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.BaseRepositoryBuilder.setup(BaseRepositoryBuilder.java:589) 
        at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.<init>(FileRepository.java:151) 
        at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.<init>(FileRepository.java:165) 
        at com.crimson.studio.Ruby.VulkanActivity.showAlert(VulkanActivity.java:58)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems JGit is not built for being used on Android and thus causes some deeper problem during startup.

There are some existing Git Client Apps for Android, see e.g. https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/guide-to-using-git-on-android/ and https://livablesoftware.com/mobile-apps-git-github-android-iphone/, but these provide a separate application for using Git on Android and not a library to include in your project.

I did only find https://github.com/rtyley/agit which provides source-code for using Git on Android, although it is unmaintained for some time, but you still might be able to extract a way of using Git in your application from it.